# Custom forms for content type

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, content-type, custom-form

Can someone give me an specific example on how to do this? Or some guidance here

I don't want to use Visual studio just Sharepoint Designer.

I already now that you can gro from SPD to the content type properties and you have an area to set your forms

[image]

But is not like when you are on a List, for example where the "Forms Box" have the New button. so how can i create a custom form from scratch?

Comment: I have so far been creating the new form within a library, as you describe by using the New Form button - Did you find a better way to do this, a way that would centralise where the custom forms are stored? I don't want to necessarily store them directly under a List/Library incase that list was ever moved/removed

Comment: I did find a way but it's not centralized at all, I assigned the Forms at CT level and then in every site I added a folder with the custom forms in that way you don't have the forms in the library but you have it at the site level